# How to fix Value exception error for combined cnn-lstm model?

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, deep-learning, lstm

My CNN and LSTM model works just fine separately  ,however my combined cnn-lstm model is not working it has to something with converting the data into 3d tensors.

The dataset: The dataset consist of eeg readings of 84 patients each patient having 60 columns(corresponding to 60 brain regions) and 11 columns(corresponding to 11 types of brain waves i.e alpha,beta,theta,etc) and the ouput is either 1,2 or 3.

Also I am trying to combine my cnn and lstm model together to get a better result.
I would like to know how i can format my data to input it to the lstm model and what changes should i make so that I can run the cnn-lstm model.

```
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Reshape


Xclshaped=Xcl.reshape(84,60,11)
model=Sequential()
model.add(Conv2D(5, (3, 3), padding='same',activation='relu', input_shape=(11, 60, 1)))
model.add(MaxPooling2D((2, 2)))

model.add(Conv2D(5, (3, 3)))
model.add(MaxPooling2D((2, 2)))


model.add(Flatten())
model.add(Reshape((9, 70)))

model.add(LSTM(5, activation='relu', return_sequences=True))
model.add(LSTM(5, activation='relu'))


model.add(Dense(3, activation='softmax'))
model.compile(optimizer='adam', loss='sparse_categorical_crossentropy', metrics=['accuracy'])

# Train the model
model.fit(Xclshaped, ylstm - 1, epochs=100)
```

**The Error**
ValueError: Exception encountered when calling layer "reshape_2" (type Reshape).

total size of new array must be unchanged, input_shape = [70], output_shape = [9, 70]

Call arguments received by layer "reshape_2" (type Reshape):
• inputs=tf.Tensor(shape=(None, 70), dtype=float32)

This is what i got when i typed the error on Bard AI

"*The error message still persists because the current input shape to the Reshape() layer is (batch_size, 70), which is a total of 70 elements. When attempting to reshape this into (batch_size, 8, 84), the total size becomes 8 * 84 = 672 elements. This exceeds the original total size of 70 elements, violating the requirement that the total size of the input tensor must remain unchanged.*"

I have tried different values for the reshape parameter but i still could not fix the error.

Comment: "not working" is not a good error message. Generally, time series data should be in the form `(batch, sequence_window, features)`. Are the 60 brain regions time features or also different features?